# How to retrieve only records that have a list of other record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `user(id, name)` and `user_detail(id, user_id, type, value)`, obviuosly the relation between them is 1:n.

user_detail contains records such:

```
(1, 1, 'HAIR', 'BROWN');
(2, 1, 'HAIR', 'BLONDE');
...
(321, 2, 'EYES', 'GREEN');
```

Now, my problem is to retrieve efficiently, all users with certain details, like `HAIR=BLONDE & EYES=GREEN & HEIGHT>140`.

What is the best solution to handle entities/relations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most *flexible* approach is using `group by` and aggregation:

```
select ud.user_id
from user_detail ud
group by ud.user_id
having sum(type = 'hair' and value = 'blonde') > 0 and
       sum(type = 'eyes' and value = 'green') > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.name,
       user_detail.id as user_detail_id, user_detail.user_id AS user_detail_user_id, user_detail.type, user_detail.value
  FROM user
         INNER JOIN user_detail
                 ON user.user_id = user_detail.user_detail_user_id
 ORDER BY user.name
```

This will return one row for each entry that exists and can be joined together in each table.  So if a single user has a "hair" and "eyes" entry, that user will have two rows listed.  If a user exists in the `user` table but has no values in the `user_detail` table, they will not be listed.  If you want them to be listed even without values, change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Note that the column aliases I used with `AS` above are completely arbitrary.  You can use whatever names you want for your columns that makes sense in your application.